# ZF using placeholders inside plugins

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, placeholder

I'm trying to implement a plugin that handles responses to the user on success or failure in a persistance transaction. When the response is false I use a _forward to the action that performed the form's submit and get my placeholder message shown but when the response is true I use a _redirect to the browse with the new record shown.

My problem is that when I use _redirect the browser doesn't show the placeholder message. I'll show the code here:

```
/**
 * Plugin
 */
class Application_Plugin_PostMessage extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

  public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
  {
      $message = $request->getParam('message');
      $error = $request->getParam('error');

      if (null !== $message || null !== $error) {
          $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
          $view = $layout->getView();
          $placeHolder = $view->placeholder('message');
          $placeHolder->setPostfix('</div>');

          if (null !== $error) {
              $placeHolder->setPrefix('<div class="errorMessage">')
                          ->append($error);
          }
          elseif (null !== $message) {
              $placeHolder->setPrefix('<div class="infoMessage">')
                          ->append($message);
          }
      }
  }

}

/**
 * Controller
 */
class My_FooController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $front->registerPlugin(new Application_Plugin_PostMessage());
    }

    ...

    public function browseAction()
    {
        ...
        // No message is shown here on redirect
        ...
    }

    public function newAction()
    {
        ...
        // This code shows the placeholder on _forward call
        ...
    }

    public function insertAction()
    {
        if(true) {
            return $this->_redirect('/my/foo/browse?message='
                 . urlencode("success message"));
        }
        else {
            return $this->_forward('new', null, null, array(
                'error' => 'error messsage'
            ));
        }
    }

}
```

I can't use _forward on success because I don't want the use of [F5] key repeats the insert action

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is what Flash Messenger is for:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.flashmessenger.basicusage

It stores messages in your session removing the need for passing messages as you are.